# How To use devise_token_auth with ActionCable for authenticating user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have a Rails 5 API with [devise_token_auth gem](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) authentications.

Now I want personal chat for authenticated users. I do not have assets as I am using API and front is in native apps and I want native apps messaging.

So how I can authenticate users to use action cable for personal messaging using devise_token_auth gem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No cookies are generally supported in Rails 5 API. See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#creating-a-new-application .

If you do a common HTTP-authentification at first somewhere at your site ( with [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gem), then you get 3 auth headers - `access_token`, `client`, `uid`.

In such case you can use the Basic authentification for your Websockets connection (according https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security#authentication-authorization ) using these 3 auth headers:

Call (I use [Chrome Simple WebSocket Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo)):

```
ws://localhost:3000/cable/?access-token=ZigtvvcKK7B7rsF_20bGHg&client=TccPxBrirWOO9k5fK4l_NA&uid=client1@example.com
```

Then process:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file. Action Cable runs in an EventMachine loop that does not support auto reloading.
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect

        params = request.query_parameters()

        access_token = params["access-token"]
        uid = params["uid"]
        client = params["client"]

        self.current_user = find_verified_user access_token, uid, client
        logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end


    protected

        def find_verified_user token, uid, client_id # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise

            user = User.find_by email: uid
# http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise_token_auth/0.1.38/DeviseTokenAuth%2FConcerns%2FUser:valid_token%3F
            if user && user.valid_token?(token, client_id)
                user
            else
                reject_unauthorized_connection
            end
        end   
  end
end
```

This is similar to the common Websockets auth https://rubytutorial.io/actioncable-devise-authentication/

Such authentication is probably enough. I believe it is **not** necessary additionally to auth at the channel subscription and on every Websocket message sent to server:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#server-side-components-connections

> For every WebSocket accepted by the server, a connection object is instantiated. This object *becomes the parent of all the channel subscriptions that are created from there on*. The connection itself does not deal with any specific application logic beyond authentication and authorization.

So if your connection is `identified_by :current_user`, you can later access `current_user` wherever inside your `FooChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel`! Example:

```
class AppearanceChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed

    stream_from "appearance_channel"

    if current_user

      ActionCable.server.broadcast "appearance_channel", { user: current_user.id, online: :on }

      current_user.online = true

      current_user.save!

    end


  end

  def unsubscribed

    if current_user

      # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "appearance_channel", { user: current_user.id, online: :off }

      current_user.online = false

      current_user.save!      

    end


  end 

end
```

PS I you want to use cookies in Rails 5 API, you can switch it on:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#other-middleware

**config/application.rb**

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#adding-other-modules

**controllers/api/application_controller.rb**

```
class Api::ApplicationController < ActionController::API

    include ActionController::Cookies
...
```

Comment: How do you get the token in cable.js file? `App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('/cable/' + token);` I can't figure how to get the token from the user.

Comment: There is no cable.js file here since this is a Rails API-only case: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html . Your problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826594/coffeescript-access-to-current-user/43250865#43250865

Comment: Will this keep working with rotating tokens, i.e tokens changing on each request for added security, obv i cannot re-open a ws connection everytime token changes

Answer (score 5):

Here the `auth_headers` set in the cookies by [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) are used to determine if the request is authenticated, if not the connection is refused.

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise_token_auth
        # parse cookies for values necessary for authentication
        auth_headers = JSON.parse(cookies['auth_headers'])

        uid_name          = DeviseTokenAuth.headers_names[:'uid']
        access_token_name = DeviseTokenAuth.headers_names[:'access-token']
        client_name       = DeviseTokenAuth.headers_names[:'client']

        uid        = auth_headers[uid_name]
        token      = auth_headers[access_token_name]
        client_id  = auth_headers[client_name]

        user = User.find_by_uid(uid)

        if user && user.valid_token?(token, client_id)
          user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: When authenticating by token from a native app, is there suppose to be any cookies set in the API server ??

Comment: @tommyalvarez the code you see above is from a backend that connects to a hybrid cordova application. The cordova app uses ng-token-auth which does set cookies. I guess that for a native app you would send the auth data in the headers of each request. But still the flow would be quite similar.

Comment: @quintencis, The problem is that for websockets you can't send custom headers other than the specified by the ws protocol, which of course does not include uid, access-token or client :(. I ended up sending the token, uid and client as query strings in the url, which is quite insecure.

Comment: @tommyalvarez There is some good info on the subject over here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security#authentication-authorization

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way, since our React Native app sends the authentication inside the headers:

```rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user
        access_token = request.headers['access-token']
        uid          = request.headers['uid']
        client       = request.headers['client']

        user = User.find_by_uid(uid)

        if user && user.valid_token?(access_token, client)
          logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', uid

          user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```