# Is it possible use Doorkeeper with Action Cable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable, doorkeeper

I want use Doorkeeper authorization with Action Cable. Is it possible?
Fot controllers I use `before_action doorkeeper_authorize!`

routes.rb

```
use_doorkeeper do
    skip_controllers :authorizations, :applications, :authorized_applications
end

mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

**UPDATE**

Look like approach is same as here: 
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/actioncable/ActionCable/Connection/Base

[How To use devise_token_auth with ActionCable for authenticating user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741120/how-to-use-devise-token-auth-with-actioncable-for-authenticating-user)

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user 
        #CODE RELATED TO DOORKEEPER ????

        if user && user.valid_token?
          user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes and no - you cannot use the sessions middleware in ActionCable but you can still read and write cookies so its possible but will take a little more effort.

Comment: @max I don't want use cookies. I use doorkeeper (tokens).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Developers [added this example](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Doorkeeper-and-ActionCable)

**OLD ANSWER**

Result something like it:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user 
        user = User.find_by(id: access_token.resource_owner_id) if access_token 

        if user 
          user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end

      def access_token
        params = request.query_parameters()

        @access_token ||= Doorkeeper::AccessToken.by_token(params[:access_token])
      end
  end
end
```

or

```
class CarsLocationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
     reject unless current_user
     stream_from "cars_locations"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late to answer this question but I have a cached answer for this!

Let me address the problem with @Vit-Vetal-'s answer:

This will allow action cable connection with expired `Doorkeeper::AccessToken` objects.

Here is the solution:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = authenticate!
    end

    protected

    def authenticate!
      reject_unauthorized_connection unless doorkeeper_token&.acceptable?(@_doorkeeper_scopes)

      # this will still allow expired tokens
      # you will need to check if token is valid with something like
      # doorkeeper_token&.acceptable?(@_doorkeeper_scopes)

      user = User.find_by(id: doorkeeper_token.try(:resource_owner_id))

      user || reject_unauthorized_connection
    end

    def doorkeeper_token
      ::Doorkeeper.authenticate(request)
    end
  end
end

# ...

class SomeChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
     reject unless current_user
     stream_from 'some'
  end
end
```